# How to fetch data from database without using a sub-query in following scenario?

Tags: mysql, join, select, subquery, inner-join

I had to get the town name and state from database which deployed the first reciever(a device to sense sharks).  I used the following query with a subquery computing MIN of deployed dates:

```
SELECT t.town,t.state,r.deployed FROM receiver as r
inner join township as t
on r.location=t.tid
where deployed=(select min(deployed) from receiver);
```

I got following result which is correct:
[Result from query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNdjF.png)

I tried to do the same thing by using having clause i.e without the subquery as following:

```
SELECT t.town,t.state,r.deployed FROM receiver as r
inner join township as t
on r.location=t.tid
having r.deployed=min(deployed);
```

But I got no rows from this query. My question is whats the problem with second query? Am I not using the min function properly in the query? What's the right way to write this query without  subquery so that I can get the result just as I got from the former query?

Answer (score 1):

If you *don't* care about ties, we can use a limit query here:

```sql
SELECT t.town, t.state, r.deployed
FROM receiver AS r
INNER JOIN township AS t
    ON r.location = t.tid
ORDER BY r.deployed
LIMIT 1;
```

If you *do* want all ties, then `RANK()` is another option, but that would require a subquery:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.town, t.state, r.deployed, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY r.deployed) rnk
    FROM receiver AS r
    INNER JOIN township AS t
        ON r.location = t.tid
)

SELECT town, state, deployed
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Note that some other databases (besides MySQL) do support a `QUALIFY` clause, which actually would let us use `RANK()` without a formal subquery:

```sql
SELECT t.town, t.state, r.deployed
FROM receiver AS r
INNER JOIN township AS t
    ON r.location = t.tid
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY r.deployed) = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my actual question is why isn't the second query working? What is wrong with that query?

Comment: The syntax is invalid because you are using `MIN()` and `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`.  As it turns out, MySQL has overloaded `HAVING` such that it can be used without `GROUP BY`, but apparently it can't be used in this way.

Comment: Thank you very much. That pretty much explains what was the problem with the query.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the field `deployed` both as an aggregate `MIN(deployed)` AND a non-aggregate `r.deployed` at the same time. The first query works because the subquery searches and finds ONE value, and then the main query compares ALL values, one by one, to that one found value to find the right one. These are two separate actions, both (in theory) going through their individual entire datasets. You cannot combine these two very different actions in one query without subquery.